# Laravel 4.1: Update Database on Window Close

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an internal app for my company that show's who is online. Kind of a clock in, clock out tool. If a user closes their window though, I need my database to be updated to show that they're logged out.

I am still relatively new to Laravel. I know that you can set a session to expire when the user closes the window, which I have set to true. However, I need to be able to update my database when an authenticated user closes their window. I'm not even sure if this is possible. If not, is there a way to simply show all users who are online or offline?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following post about detecting window close with javascript:

[javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

You could setup a route for decrementing the online users and fire off an AJAX method that hits that route when the onunload or onbeforeunload events fire.

Now, it wouldn't be 100% accurate as those methods also fire when the user leaves the site via a link.